# Find a basis that is not a subset of the spanning set

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ given by $W$=span$\big\{\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}3\\2\\1\\1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\\1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\2\\4\\1\end{bmatrix} \big\}$.

The first part of the question asks me to find a subset $S$ of the spanning set that is a basis for $W$. I did that by combining the vectors by column and row reducing them, and got $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}3\\-2\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\-2\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\4\\-3\\0\end{bmatrix}$. I got this method from this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127405/find-a-subset-that-forms-a-basis-for-the-span-of-a-set). Since $v_4=1.5v_3-0.5v_2$, this set is linearly dependent, so $v_1,v_2,v_3$ span. However, I'm unsure because the last entry of the vectors are all $0$, which cannot be a basis for $W$ since a vector spanned by the spanning set of $W$ can be $2$, for example, if we add $v_1+v_2$ and get $2$ in the last entry.

The next part asks me to find a basis that is not a subset. I think I just need to find a basis such that the last row is $0$ and not a subset of $W$, but I'm not sure. If my logic is correct, then I want to find four linearly independent vectors such that the last entry of all four vectors is $0$. I cannot see how I can find one without being linearly dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the thread you referenced, and using your work so far, since columns $1,2$ and $3$ are a basis after row reduction,  you can conclude that the first three vectors (from the *original* set), for instance, are a basis that fulfills your requirements...  note that vectors $1,2$ and $4$ would also work  (so would $1,3$ and $4$, or $2,3$ and $4$, it appears) ...

Then, for the second part, just change one or more vectors by multiplication by a scalar other than $0$ or $1$...  (this will preserve linear independence).

Comment: Yes, say I take the first three vectors as a basis. That answers part 1. For part 2, I can multiply the first vector by 2, so it becomes [2,0,0,0]. This gives a basis for $W$, and this basis isn't a subset of the spanning set we found. Correct?

Comment: @user539807 wait.  You need to take the first three from the _original_ set...

Comment: @user539807 that's what the thread explains...

Comment: So it's saying, since I showed that (by row reducing) the set only needs three vectors, I can just take 3 vectors from the original set. This is a subset of the original set and it's a basis for $W$. Right?

Comment: @user539807 what's interesting is that row reduction preserves linear independence of the columns...  so, if, as in this case, vectors $1,2$ and $3$ are a basis _after_ row reduction,  then vectors $1,2$ and $3$ _before_ row reduction will also be a basis...  You need to use this correspondence,  as the problem asks for a basis from the _original_ set...  what row reduction does is make it easy to see which columns form a basis...  Then you go back to the original set and take the same columns ($1,2$ and $3$rd, or $1,2$ and $4$th, in this case...)

Comment: The problem just asks to "determine a subset $S$ of the spanning set that is a basis for $W$". So, I think taking the vectors 1, 2, 3 after row reduction or taking the original vectors 1, 2, 3 are both fine.

Comment: @user539807 the spanning set consists of just $4$ specific vectors.  So you only have $4$ choices for the elements of your subset S...

Comment: @user539807 also, in general row reduction can change the column space...

Answer (score 1):

What was the subset you found for the first part of the question?

Your solution is not correct, since the first and last vectors are the same. Hence, they are not linearly independent and thus cannot form a basis. However, by definition, a basis is a set of vectors that is linearly independent and spans the space. Hence, you need to find $d$ linearly independent vectors where $d$ is the dimension of $W$ which you should have found in your first part. One way to do that is to start from the basis that you found in the first part and then exchange vectors in your basis with vectors from the space $W$ while preserving linear independence.

Comment: Neither does the purported basis span $W$—there’s no way to get a non-zero fourth coordinate.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake. I think I need the last row to be zeros, so the last entry of each vector to be 0. Thus, I'm not sure how I can make 4 linearly independent vectors.

Comment: I think the dimension of $W$ is at most 3. Hence, you cannot find 4 linearly independent vectors that lie in $W$.

Comment: I updated my answer. I think if I just take 3 vectors from my answer in part 1, it would form a basis for the space $W$, and it is a subset of the spanning set.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done the calculations for your specific question, but say for example $W$ works out to be $3$-dimensional and a basis is $\{u,v,w\}$, a subset of the given set.  Then for example $\{2u,3v,4w\}$ is also a basis which is not a subset of the given set.

Your proposed answer cannot be right as it is linearly dependent.

Just a thought... are you sure the question wasn't "find a subset which is not a basis"?

Comment: Right, thanks for pointing that out. To clarify, the first part of the question asks for a subset $S$ of the spanning set; this subset must also be a basis for $W$. The second part of the question asks for a basis for $W$; this basis must not be a subset of the spanning set.